How to validate form on a swipe gesture with PopScope
As written in title, i would like to know if there is a way to validate a Form after the user executed a swipe gesture to pop the current route.
I am expecting that when the user is executing the swipe, at some point (let's say at the half of the animation), my callback to validate the Form is called, and I can show a popup to inform the user.
I already managed to call the validation callback when a pop is executed from the AppBar or from the physical button, but I need on the swipe gesture as well, and using a GestureDetector widget is not really what I want since it will remove the system animation.

It would be nice to have a simple version of your code so someone could work on a solution on top of that! Anyway, I will post my answer below!

If I have understood your question correctly, here's the solution.
class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();

  bool get canSubmit => _formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? true;

  void submitForm() {
    if (canSubmit) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvokedWithResult: (didPop, result) {
        if (didPop) return;
        submitForm();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Form'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Full name'),
                  validator: (value) =>
                      value?.trim().isEmpty ?? true ? 'Provide a name' : null,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 16),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: submitForm,
                  child: const Text('Submit'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


it's not working as I want, since setting canPop to false blocks the swipe to pop native gesture

Could you please describe your desired behavior a little more? When using the back gesture, my solution will pop the current route only when the form is valid, if it is not, it will not pop it!
